# Stanford Parser questions

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am writing a project that works with NLP (natural language parser). I am using the stanford parser.

I create a thread pool that takes sentences and run the parser with them.
When I create one thread its all works fine, but when I create more, I get errors.
The "test" procedure is finding words that have some connections.
If I do an synchronized its supposed to work like one thread but still I get errors.
My problem is that I have errors on this code:

```
public synchronized String test(String s,LexicalizedParser lp )
{

    if (s.isEmpty()) return "";
    if (s.length()>80) return "";
    System.out.println(s);
    String[] sent = s.split(" ");
 Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sent));
TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();
List list = new ArrayList(tdl);


//for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
//System.out.println(list.get(1).toString());

//remove scops and numbers like sbj(screen-4,good-6)->screen good

 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\((.*?)\\-\\d+,(.*?)\\-\\d+\\).*");

       if (list.size()>2){
    // Split input with the pattern
        Matcher m = p.matcher(list.get(1).toString());
        //check if the result have more than  1 groups
       if (m.find()&& m.groupCount()>1){
           if (m.groupCount()>1)
           {
               System.out.println(list);
 return  m.group(1)+m.group(2);
    }}
}
        return "";

}
```

the errors that I have are:

> at blogsOpinions.ParserText.(ParserText.java:47)
>     at blogsOpinions.ThreadPoolTest$1.run(ThreadPoolTest.java:50)
>     at blogsOpinions.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPoolTest.java:196)
>   Recovering using fall through
>   strategy: will construct an (X ...)
>   tree. Exception in thread
>   "PooledThread-21"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord
>
> at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.apply(LexicalizedParser.java:289)
>       at blogsOpinions.ParserText.test(ParserText.java:174)
>       at blogsOpinions.ParserText.insertDb(ParserText.java:76)
>       at blogsOpinions.ParserText.(ParserText.java:47)
>       at blogsOpinions.ThreadPoolTest$1.run(ThreadPoolTest.java:50)
>       at blogsOpinions.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPoolTest.java:196)

and how can i get the discription of the subject like the screen is very good, and I want to get screen good from the list the I get and not like `list.get(1)`.

Comment: and how can i get the discription of the subject like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `LexicalizedParser.parse` on a `List` of `String`s; it expects a list of [`HasWord`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/HasWord.html) objects. It's much easier to call the [`apply`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser.html#apply%28java.lang.Object%29) method on your input string. This will also run a proper tokenizer on your input (instead of your simple `split` on spaces).

To get relations such as subjectness out of the returned `Tree`, call its [`dependencies`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html#dependencies%28%29) member.

Comment: thanks i did like you said :Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(s); but know I have error in line:GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse); the erorr is Exception in thread "PooledThread-11" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure(edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructureFactory.newGrammaticalStructure(GrammaticalStructureFactory.java:104)
        at blogsOpinions.ParserText.test(ParserText.java:181

Comment: Don't build a `GrammaticalStructure`, just call `Tree.dependencies`.

Comment: what vitaly is using, is mentioned in the javadocs. They should correct it and change it as larsmans said. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I witnessed the same stack trace. Turned out I was loading two instances of the LexicalizedParser in the same JVM. This seemed to be the problem. When I made sure only one instance is created, I was able to call `lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sent))` just fine.